# Cmake, Boost parsing command line

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have a problem. I am using Cmake and boost with VS 2015.

I intend to develop a tool using cgal and assimp. To convert file formats into my own. However, I encountered a problem and might be simple but cant see it.

When I press F5, I get debug error like the two images I have attached. I have also attached my code. The pictures are here:

[image]

[image]

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct CMDOPTIONS {
    std::string input, output, directory;
    int points;
};

namespace po = boost::program_options;

bool process_command_line(int argc, char **argv, CMDOPTIONS &cmdoptions1) {

    if (argv == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        po::options_description desc("Program Usage");
        po::options_description desc ("Program Usage");
        desc.add_options()
            ("halp, h", "Halp!")
            ("input, i", po::value<std::string>(&cmdoptions1.input), "Specify Input")
            ("output, o", po::value<std::string>(&cmdoptions1.output) ,"Specify Output")
            ("points, p", po::value<int>(&cmdoptions1.points),  "% of reduced points")
            ("directory, d", po::value<std::string>(&cmdoptions1.directory)->required(), "set the directory");

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << desc << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        // trolololol XD
        if (vm.count("input")) {
            &cmdoptions1.input;
        }

        if (vm.count("output")) {
            &cmdoptions1.output;
        }

        if (vm.count("points")) {
            &cmdoptions1.points;
        }

        if (vm.count("directory")) {
            &cmdoptions1.directory;
        }

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    } catch (int e) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown error!" << e << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, CMDOPTIONS &cmdoptions1) {

    bool result = process_command_line(argc, argv, cmdoptions1);
    if (!result)
        return -1;

    std::cout << "input" << &cmdoptions1.input << std::endl;
    std::cout << "output" << &cmdoptions1.output << std::endl;
    std::cout << "points" << &cmdoptions1.points << std::endl;
    std::cout << "directory\t" << &cmdoptions1.directory << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Check where the assert originates. You're landed into the debugger. Use it!

Comment: Yes I after pressing Retry I am shown where it stopped at desc..add_options. Unclear why that is a problem.

Comment: well you get the window that you hit a breakpoint. Just use the break button and investigate. You are using boost program options wrong.... visual studio should point you to where and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cmdoptions1` is uninitialized.

In fact, your `main` should not compile (what kind of signature is that?).

Besides, you're printing pointers to the config values.

Thirdly, the compiler doesn't get your intent when you type `trololol XD`.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e89e003ac8ccc38)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct CMDOPTIONS {
    std::string input, output, directory;
    int points;
};

namespace po = boost::program_options;

bool process_command_line(int argc, char **argv, CMDOPTIONS &cmdoptions1) {

    if (argv == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        po::options_description desc("Program Usage");
        desc.add_options()
            ("halp, h", "Halp!")
            ("input, i", po::value<std::string>(&cmdoptions1.input), "Specify Input")
            ("output, o", po::value<std::string>(&cmdoptions1.output) ,"Specify Output")
            ("points, p", po::value<int>(&cmdoptions1.points),  "% of reduced points")
            ("directory, d", po::value<std::string>(&cmdoptions1.directory)->required(), "set the directory");

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << desc << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    } catch (int e) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown error!" << e << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    CMDOPTIONS cmdoptions1;
    bool result = process_command_line(argc, argv, cmdoptions1);
    if (!result)
        return -1;

    std::cout << "input"       << cmdoptions1.input     << std::endl;
    std::cout << "output"      << cmdoptions1.output    << std::endl;
    std::cout << "points"      << cmdoptions1.points    << std::endl;
    std::cout << "directory\t" << cmdoptions1.directory << std::endl;
}
```